# Spring Data JPA error: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, date

I'm working on a project that've to extract some entities from database, and compute them using some formulas. This entity contains a filed date mapped to date column using format: `yyyy-MM-dd`. One single row fail containing the date `2009-06-01`

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.findFirst2ByBeginnigOfYearIsNull(Unknown Source)
at com.peaqock.service.VlAnService.computeNotCalculatedVlans(VlAnService.java:156)
at com.peaqock.service.VlAnService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2dad4910.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.io.JdbcDateValueFactory.createFromDate(JdbcDateValueFactory.java:66)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.io.JdbcDateValueFactory.createFromDate(JdbcDateValueFactory.java:39)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:46)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:46)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:66)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:70)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:225)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:78)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNonStringValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:658)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDateOrTimestampValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:671)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:816)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:827)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DateTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DateTypeDescriptor.java:76)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.getResultList(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 19 common frames omitted
```

I spent some hours digging into this error, I finally found that Morocco Has first switched to summer time at this specific date: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/morocco/casablanca, So the time `00` doesn't exist. I tried all the solutions suggested here: https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/ but unfortunately none of them works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This what gives me the solution :

I debugged the driver to find out what was happening. It turns out that the Calendar objects that Hibernate sends to the JDBC API gets completely ignored. When the driver runs in the useLegacyDatetimeCode=true mode, which is default. The driver get’s the argument – and then simply choose to make another Calendar like this: Calendar.getInstance(). The effect of that, is that the driver uses the timezone that is default to the JVM.

Notice that MySQL JDBC drivers also support another argument: serverTimezone=TIMEZONEHERE. Set that to UTC, skip the Hibernate configuration, and you have another solution. This time, however, tightly bound to the specific driver.

My solution is: `jdbc:mysql://<ip>/<db>?useSSL=false&&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

Comment: The problem of this solution is that your dates will be persisted in UTC, what is a problem if you already have data in your DB. Not sure how already saved dates (in the original timezone) will be retrieved, but believe that will be a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it like me.

jdk1.8
mysql lastest

**excute sql :**

`show variables like "%time_zone%";`

**Then set like this:**

`db.url=jdbc:mysql://ip:point/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&serverTimezone=&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

replace the `serverTimezone` by select result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is related to `java.util.Date`. You can solve it easily by using `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to restart `mysql server`,try to roback `mysql-connector-java` to `version5.1.49`